# Mysterious 500 error with AWS Lambda; unable to debug

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an API that I host using Lambda (nodejs), with API-gateway. I'm using serverless to deploy.

Generally things have been fine, but while I was working on a specific function today, I started to receive HTTP 500 errors when hitting the endpoint. However, while there were still API-Gateway access logs for the end point, there were no Cloudwatch logs for the lambda functions getting hit. I was able to verify that the Authorizer was getting hit successfully, and not returning any issue (if it was, it would have been a 401). After using CLI tools to invoke the function from the command line, the 500 error went away and I was able to successfully hit the endpoints again.

Has anyone ever ran into this before? If I'm missing a debug step, I would really like to know. It was really concerning that my API could be generating 500 errors with no paper trail to help me understand what was happening.

Comment: In the Api Gateway Logs for that request, what is the complete response message? And how much time it takes to respond?

Comment: it's a short log and it only logs the inbound request, not the response. However in my experience the responses were nearly instant, <200ms

"requestId": "XX",
    "ip": "XX",
    "requestTime": "10/Jan/2022:05:50:20 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "routeKey": "POST XX",
    "status": "500",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "35"

Answer (score 0):

You can check your role and permissions ,this link could help you https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-lambda-stage-variable-500/

Also you can debug further with X-ray : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html

Comment: I'll give x-ray a try. I went through the guide you linked already; but I don't think any of it applies as the function was working perfectly fine and is now doing so again without me changing anything in that guide

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem i.e. Authorizer running successfully but request returning 500 error without actually hitting the target endpoint lambda. After some trial and error I found that its occurring due to inclusion of array and object based properties in 'context' part of the IAM policy which authoriser was generating. As soon as I replaced array and object properties in context with string values it worked like a charm.